# How can one solve the following equation for Mathcad cannot calculate that

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following equation:

$$\frac{1}{p_1^{1/(\gamma-1)}}\left[\frac{1}{\gamma}\left(a_1-\frac{\gamma-1}{2}U\right)^2\right]^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}=p_5\left(1+\frac{\gamma(\gamma+1)}{4}\frac{U^2}{a_5^2}+\gamma\frac{U}{a_5}\sqrt{\frac{(\gamma+1)^2}{16}\frac{U^2}{a_5^2}+1}\right)$$

which I have to solve with respect to $U$ (all the other parameters are known).

I tried to use Mathcad but it was effortless. If I try to solve manually I'm stuck because it's highly irrational in the left part.

Yet I need the exact solution. Could someone propose an advice how to solve the equation?

Comment: Are you sure that exact solution can be found algebraically?

Comment: I am. The equation has arised from Hugoniot conditions, so it must have the algebraic solution.

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов The solution will depend on the value of the parameter, in particular $\gamma$.

Comment: I am aware of that :) That's why I wrote the other parameters are known. I just need some advice on how to begin solving it.

Comment: I would be surprised by an analytical solution. But, who knows ?